# Why is a repelling fixed point also an isolated fixed point?

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

This is Exercise $1.5.2$ in *Introduction to Dynamical Systems* by Michael Brin and Garrett Stuck.

> Let $X$ be a locally compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a continuous map. We say that a fixed point $p$ is repelling if $f(p) = p$, and there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\overline{U} \subset f(U)$, and $\bigcap_{n\ge 0} f^{-n}(U) = \{p\}$. Show that a repelling fixed point is an isolated fixed point, i.e., there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ that contains no other fixed points.

If this is not the case, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a point $x \in X$ different from $p$, such that $d(x,p) < \epsilon$, and $f(x) = x$. Thus, we can find a sequence of fixed points $\{x_n\}$ converging to $p$, such that $d(x_n,p) < 2^{-n}$ for all $n\ge 1$. As $x_n \to p$, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n\ge N$. I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I haven't worked out the details, but what is $\bigcap_{n \geq 0} f^{-n}(U)$? It seems like that might be the key to finding a contradiction to $p$ being repelling.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That's a good question - one that confuses me too. The book has not explicitly stated what $f^{-n}$ is, but it seems reasonable that they assume $f^{-1}$ exists, and define $f^{-n}$ as $f^{-1} \circ \ldots\circ f^{-1}$ ($n$ times.)

Comment: @stoic-santiago: it might help to invoke the existence criterion for a repelling fixed point (i.e. it might help to write the neighborhood $U$ as $U(p)$): you only need one "nearby" (hypothetical) fixed point (that isn't $p$.)

Comment: So any $U$ contain such an $x$ and $f^{-n}(U)$ contains also $x$.

Comment: @TLDR That might be overkill? The book hasn't developed an existence criterion for repelling fixed points, yet.

Comment: @stoic-santiago: by "existence criterion", I simply meant the fact that if $p$ is well and truly a repelling fixed point, then a certain mathematical object (with potentially useful properties) exists associated with $p$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Given $U = U(p)$ as in the definition, and the sequence of fixed points $x_n \to p$, we can surely find a fixed point $y \ne p$ such that $y \in U$. Since $f(y) = y$, we have $f^{-1}(y) = y$, and so $f^{-n}(y) = y$ for all $n \ge 0$. Therefore, $y \in \bigcap_{n \ge 0} f^{-n}(U) = \{p\}$, which is a contradiction since $y \ne p$. Looks good? @TLDR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{-1}(U)$ here means the inverse image of $U$ under $f$: i.e., $\{x : f(x) \in U\}$. And $f^{-n}$ means the $n$-th iterate of the inverse image operation. If you take $V = U$, then $V$ contains no fixed points other than $p$: if $q \in U$ were some other fixed point, then you'd have that $q \in f^{-n}(U)$ for every $n$ (because $f(q) = q$), so that $q \in \bigcap_{n \ge 0}f^{-n}(U)$ contradicting the assumption that $ \bigcap_{n \ge 0}f^{-n}(U) = \{p\}$